# psycopg2 - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.8

I'm using python 3.8 and psycopg2

I'm trying to insert a registry in the database.
I have a function that formats a query and send as result a list with 2 values, one is the query and the other the values.

I made a test and put a fixed value with the exact value of the result list query[1] and worked without error, but when I use the query[1] as values instead the value by itself I got this error:

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

At my log I have these values for the query list, result of my query construction function.

```
 ['INSERT INTO country (code, name, flag, update_time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)', "('US', 'USA', 'https://example.com/flags/us.svg', 1596551810)"]
```

query[0]

```
 INSERT INTO country (code, name, flag, update_time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

query[1]

```
('US', 'USA', 'https://example.com/flags/us.svg', 1596551810)
```

This is the code snipet

`

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query_insert = query[0]
    query_values = tuple(query[1])
    cursor.execute(query_insert,(query_values))
```

I tried to put it as tuple, use parentheses, but error persists.
If I put the value of the query[1] at my code,as values, work well, so I suppose that the error is at the values part of the cursor.execute parameters.

Any help is welcome !

Comment: Please show your python code where `query[1]` has its value assigned.

Comment: Show the output of  ```cur.mogrify(query_insert,(query_values))```

Comment: In your log output the `query_values` are shown as string instead of tuple.